# new RegExp inot working in Edge and FireFox

Tags: regex, browser

for some reasons new RegExp is not working in Edge and FireFox. How can I get around this?

```
var arrOfWordsToHighlight =  ["microsoft","excel"];

function escapeRegExp(arrOfWordsToHighlight) {
  return arrOfWordsToHighlight.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
}

var pattern = new RegExp("(?<![\\w-])(" + arrOfWordsToHighlight.map(escapeRegExp).join("|") + ")(?![\\w-])", "gi");

$('#job').highlightWithinTextarea({
    highlight: pattern
});
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/seb_london/wm9yqazj

Comment: Could you expand on *"not working"*? If you mean https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_regexp_lastmatch note that's non-standard.

Comment: Your jsfiddle link is broken.

Comment: Lookbehind is not supported in many browsers. For example Firefox and Edge (depending on version number) don't support it. https://caniuse.com/#search=lookbehind

Comment: Can you please try this link: https://jsfiddle.net/seb_london/wm9yqazj/38/ . You'll see in Chrome some highlighted keywords in the text area, but not in Edge at Firefox. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: You need to use `new RegExp("([^\\w-]|^)(" + arrOfWordsToHighlight.map(escapeRegExp).join("|") + ")(?![\\w-])", "gi")` and fix the `highlightWithinTextarea` function to restore Group 1 contents and only highlight the Group 2 contents

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm not sure what you mean between group 1 and group 2 contents?

Comment: In my regex above, there are 2 capturing groups Otherwise, the symbol before the match [will also be highlighted](https://jsfiddle.net/c327jvdb/)

Comment: Check [this modification](https://jsfiddle.net/4brmcvho/1/)

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, but your jsfiddle example doesn't work for me, the highlighting of the keywords is all over the place in Chrome.