# Regex lookaround alternative for Microsoft Edge and Safari

Tags: javascript, regex, safari, microsoft-edge, regex-lookarounds

The following pattern works fine in Chrome and FF, but not in Microsoft Edge and Safari. What could be the workaround to make it work in these browsers?

```
var pattern = new RegExp('(?<!\\p{L}\\p{M}*|[\\p{N}_-])(?:' + keywords.map(escapeRegExp).join('|') + ')(?![\\p{L}\\p{N}_-])', 'igu');
```

**Edit:**

I've created a https://jsfiddle.net/seb_london/64a9m0L1/17/ - type php, java or .net in the textarea. The keywords will get highlighted in Chrome but not in Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0, I believe it's the same issue in Safari.

Comment: If you want the exact same functionality, you won't like it. The consensus here is usually to use some workarounds. Say, whitespace boundaries.

Comment: What are not working. I tested on EDGE and var pattern = new RegExp('(?<!\\p{L}\\p{M}*|[\\p{N}_-])(?:abc)(?![\\p{L}\\p{N}_-])', 'igu');'.abc.'.match(pattern) returns ['abc']

Comment: Thanks. It's a Regex that I'm using with the https://github.com/lonekorean/highlight-within-textarea plugin, but I haven't been able to make it work as a code snippet to show how it works. With this plugin/regex I can highlight words in Chrome and FF but not in Edge and Safari.

Comment: Can you try to use a more simple regex, to check if plugin are working? You are using "\p{L}", "\p{M}" that are supported on PHP, but maybe not um javascript (in javascript the "\p{L}" matches literaly 'p{L}', not any kind of letter from any language like in PHP. Try to replace it with "\s" (space). Try new RegExp('(?<=\\s)(?:' + keywords.map(escapeRegExp).join('|') + ')(?=\\s)', 'igu');

Comment: Your new ReExp doesn't work (even in Chrome). But I get your point, I'll look into simplifying it for JS. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? I tested it with the pulgin you mentioned, and filled some parameters (`keywords` and `escapeRegExp`). I found that it works correctly in Edge (highlighting specific text). Here is my [test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIzdX.png). If possible, please provide a code example that can reproduce the problem, which will help solve the problem, thank you for your understanding.

Comment: I've created a https://jsfiddle.net/seb_london/64a9m0L1/17/ type php, java or .net in the textarea. The keywords will get highlighted in Chrome but not in Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0, I believe it's the same issue in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you are currently using [Legacy Edge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/what-is-microsoft-edge-legacy-3e779e55-4c55-08e6-ecc8-2333768c0fb0). But Microsoft has stopped supporting it since March 9, 2021. So I think you can try the new Microsoft Edge, which has been updated to version 93.0.961.52.

And it can correctly execute the code you mentioned. This is a simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Highlight Within Textarea</title>
    <!--<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Droid+Sans+Mono" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- highlight-within-textarea CSS/JS -->
    <link href="https://lonekorean.github.io/highlight-within-textarea/jquery.highlight-within-textarea.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://lonekorean.github.io/highlight-within-textarea/jquery.highlight-within-textarea.js"></script>
    <!-- custom styles for highlight-within-textarea -->
    <style>

        .hwt-container {
            background-color: #f8f9fa;
        }

        .hwt-content {
            width: 760px;
            height: 100px;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #adb5bd;
            color: inherit;
            font: 18px/25px 'Droid Sans Mono', sans-serif;
        }

        .hwt-input:focus {
            outline-color: #495057;
        }

        .hwt-content mark {
            border-radius: 3px;
            background-color: #d0bfff;
        }

            .hwt-content mark.red {
                background-color: #ffc9c9;
            }

            .hwt-content mark.blue {
                background-color: #a3daff;
            }

            .hwt-content mark.yellow {
                background-color: #ffec99;
            }

        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            max-width: 800px;
            margin: 40px auto;
            padding: 0 20px;
            font: 18px/1.4 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            color: #495057;
            background-color: #f1f3f5;
        }

        a {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            padding: 10px 30px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            color: #f8f9fa;
            background-color: #495057;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        section {
            margin-top: 60px;
        }

        code {
            padding: 0 5px;
            font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            background-color: #dee2e6;
        }

        script {
            display: block;
            margin-top: 10px;
            padding-left: 15px;
            border-left: 5px solid #adb5bd;
            background-color: #e9ecef;
            white-space: pre-wrap;
            font: 14px/1.5 'Droid Sans Mono', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- general styles to make this page look decent -->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Highlight Within Textarea</h1>
    <section>
        <h2>RegExp</h2>
        <p>Don't forget the <code>g</code> (find all) and <code>i</code> (case-insensitive) flags if you need them.</p>
        <textarea class="regex-example">Dog, cat,php, chicken,java, .net ,goose. Dogs, cats, chickens, geese.</textarea>
        <script>
            const arrOfWordsToHighlight = ["php", "java", ".net"];

            function escapeRegExp(arrOfWordsToHighlight) {
                return arrOfWordsToHighlight.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
            }

            var pattern = new RegExp('(?<!\\p{L}\\p{M}*|[\\p{N}_-])(?:' + arrOfWordsToHighlight.map(escapeRegExp).join('|') + ')(?![\\p{L}\\p{N}_-])', 'igu');
            console.log(pattern);
            $('.regex-example').highlightWithinTextarea({
                /* highlight: /dogs?|cats?|g(oo|ee)se/gi*/
                highlight: pattern
            });
        </script>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Many thanks for checking in the latest version of Edge, happy it works. But it's not highlighting words in Safari 12, I don't have the latest version 14.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew fixed it a while ago, but I didn't get it at that time. Now I made it work in Safari too. Thanks Wiktor for your time, and everyone. Original post with the answer.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59139887/new-regexp-inot-working-in-edge-and-firefox?noredirect=1#comment104514551_59139887